# Using tweenr and gganimate with bar plots

Tags: r, gganimate

How do I use tweenr along with gganimate to create a very smooth animation between the two bar charts below?

```
library(tweenr)
library(gganimate)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  decile = c("lowest", "second", "third", "lowest", "second", "third"),
  change = c(1, 2, -0.5, -2, -3, 4),
  year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L)
)

df2001 <- filter(df, year == 2001)
df2002 <- filter(df, year == 2002)

ggplot(df2001, aes(x = decile, y = change)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5)) +
  theme_minimal()

ggplot(df2002, aes(x = decile, y = change)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: changed `transition_states` and `ease_aes` to spend more time on transition, increased font size, and changed `animate` terms to make duration longer & movement slower.

```
a <- ggplot(df, aes(x = decile, y = change/2, 
                    height = change, width = 0.9, group = decile)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5), name = "change") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  transition_states(year, wrap = T, transition_length = 10, state_length = 1) +
  ease_aes("cubic-in-out")

animate(a, fps = 30, duration = 10, width = 500, height = 300)
# Use up to two of fps, nframes, and duration to define the
#   length and frame rate of the animation.
```

[image]

---

Please note, I used `geom_tile` above because `geom_col` produced this unconventional behavior upon transition. I suspect the drawn `geom_col` doesn't distinguish between its baseline and its extent, but rather between its min and max, resulting in "sliding" animation. (Curious if others see an easier workaround.)

```
a <- ggplot(df, aes(x = decile, y = change)) +
  geom_col() +
  ...
```

[image]

Comment: Some questions: Why did you change from geom_col to geom_tile? Why is the resolution of the graph itself so low? ie the axis labels. And most importantly, how do you do a slow, smooth version. If you reduce fps to 10, the animation is slow, but jerky. This is why I thought tweenr would be required to create the intermediate frames.

Comment: Edited above. You can control font size with your theme. You can control resolution in the `animate` call, where you can also make it as long in duration and as high in frame rate as you like. gganimate uses tweenr under the hood, both by the esteemed Thomas Pedersen:  https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/blob/master/DESCRIPTION

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get how to "control resolution" from animate. Size? Yes. Resolution???

Comment: By resolution, are you talking about dpi? I don't believe a GIF has a way to control this, rather just total dimensions. If you are using another device, like av_renderer(), for instance to make an mp4, you can control dpi, but the syntax will depend on the renderer. Look at the options for `animate` for more...

Comment: The sharpness of the text of a static ggplot is much greater than the output of animate's animated gif. I will look into av_renderer() as you suggest.